# JQuery Selecting the text next to radio buttons

Tags: jquery, replace, radio-button, checked

I need some help. I have a div inside which there are some radio buttons generated dynamically with a piece of text next to each radio button also generated dynamically, inside a  element, like below:

```
<div class="mother_div"> 
   <input type="radio" class="child_radio" name="amount" value="0" />
   <span class="child_text">0.0 some text</span>
   <input type="radio" class="child_radio" name="amount" value="1" />
   <span class="child_text">1.0 some text</span>
   <input type="radio" class="child_radio" name="amount" value="2" />
   <span class="child_text">2.0 some text</span>
   <input type="radio" class="child_radio" name="amount" value="3" />
   <span class="child_text">3.0 some text</span>
```

I need a Jquery method or function that would allow me to start with the mother_div and upon user clicking/checking a radio button (they are all unchecked to start with), to replace the text inside the span with the "child_text" class with a different string of HTML.

What I tried so far is this, but it doesn't work:

```
$("div.mother_div input:radio[name=child_radio]").click(function() {
    var newHTML= "some HTML to insert";
    $(span.child_text).html(newHTML);
});
```

Any thoughts or suggestions highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("div.mother_div input").click(function() {
   var newHTML= "some HTML to insert";
   //this will change text next to radio button clicked
   $(this).next('span.child_text').html(newHTML);  

   //this will change text next to all the radio buttons
   $(this).parent().children('span.child_text').html(newHTML);
});
```

Your Selector is invalid. You can check [change clicked one only](http://jsfiddle.net/y8yRn/1/) or [change all](http://jsfiddle.net/y8yRn/3/) demo on jsFiddle.net

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. I ended up using Amar's solution - works like a charm! BTW, how can I make the HTML in the span revert back to original once another radio button is clicked?

Comment: You can store the original text and clicked item in some variable, and restore it when ever you want to. Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y8yRn/4/). Also if you are satisfied with answer, accept the answer read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.mother_div input:radio[name="child_radio"]').click(function() {
    var newHTML= "some HTML to insert";
    $(this).next('span.child_text').html(newHTML);
});
```